# When does the daily error limit for the analytics API reset?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

According to docs, the daily request limits all reset at midnight pacific, but the daily error limit just says per day.  Is this also reset at midnight or is this a rolling 24 hour period?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller this isnt customer support. this is a question about the quota for the Google analytics api and how it works.

Comment: Sorry, on their own support page they suggest posting here and tagging with google-analytics-api. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an authoritative answer but based on a lot of experimentation over the last week it looks like it is a 24-hour rolling window and not based on a set time, like the daily max request rate limits.

Answer (score 1):

## daily error limit

The daily error limit is something that they added a few years back.  The idea behind is is that if your application sends to many errors.  Error's being making requests that are invalid.  This is not the errors realted to the quota or going to fast.

Google added this error to stop people looping though bad requests and not fixing their code.   The thing is I have never heard of anyone actually hitting this limit.

I was told at the time that if your app continues with these errors the length of time you are banned gets longer each time.   I say banned because it is actually like a ban Google is stopping you from making requests that are useless as they are wrong.

So when will it reset off hand i remember something about days or a perm ban.  If you can give me the full error message you are getting i can contact the team for you and get some more details.  Or PM me on twitter and if you give me the project id i might be able to get you some info that way as well.

Comment: Im talking about the error limit, not the request limit.  The request limits are pretty clear but the errors just have a count per hour and day.   I assume the hour is a rolling hour but the day limit is not clear.

Comment: The day limit will reset at midnight west cost usa time.   If for example i try to make more then 50000 requests from my app i have to wait until the next day before i can make anymore

Comment: Again you seem to talking about the daily request limit (50,000) and not the daily ERROR limit (50).

Comment: Well the daily error limit is something completely different would you please edit your question and include the full error message.

Comment: I dont understand, I mention in the question that I am talking about the daily error limit and I specify that I am not talking about the daily request limit. There is no specific error I am talking about, but the limit in the number of errors per day that they allow you to have.

Comment: Sorry i miss read check update,  my twitter link can be found in my profile here on SO

Comment: I understand what an error limit is and why they do it, just trying to understand at what time the count resets. The errors are inconsistent and the same request will sometimes return a 500 and sometimes be fine so I am not looking for help understanding the error, just trying to implement backoff logic that is consistent with their policies.

Comment: Can you **please** post the error message you are getting.  How do you know you are hitting the error limit? If you are seeing 500 errors these are server errors and having nothing to do with your code.   **What is the error message. That makes you think you are hitting the Error Limit?** To be clear 500 errors will not contribute towards error limit count its the server that's failing not you.   Your question does not mention that you are looing for information on how to  [Implementing Exponential Backoff](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/errors#backoff)

Comment: 500 and 503 errors do contribute to the error limit, as do errors that I never see because my request times out. I saw this happen all the time while we were evolving the backoff and the error handling logic, where after a bunch of 500s we would get 429s for surpassing the error limit. I am not looking for help in troubleshooting specific errors and I am doing exponential backoff. You are attempting to answer a question not being asked, which is nice but simply not what I am asking. I was just looking to know when the error count resets because that is not documented.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that the daily server error quotas are 24-hour rolling windows. We updated the [documentation on sever error quotas](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas#reporting_apis_request_errors) on the Developer's site:

> Server error rate quotas are enforced over rolling windows of time for each of the hourly and daily error rate quotas. One hour after a project and view pair's first server error, the quota resets. If a project and view pair sends 10 server errors in one hour, the project and view pair is blocked from the API until the hour after the first server error elapses.
>
> For example if a project and view pair have not sent a server error in the last 24 hours, this project and view will have used 0 of its 50 quota. Let's say this project and view now send a server error at 6:12 AM. If this project and view send 49 additional server errors before 6:12 AM of the following day, this project and view will be blocked until 6:12 AM of the following day. At 6:12 AM of the following day, the server error rate quota will completely reset for this project and view.

There are two sever error quotas: 1) daily & 2) hourly. If either of these quotas are exhausted, the project and view pair are blocked from making requests for up to the next 24 hours or up to the next hour (respectively). The duration of being blocked does **not** increase if a project and view pair repeatedly exhaust this quota. For example, it is impossible to be blocked for more than 24 hours.

Thanks,

The Google Analytics Team